# How can one get last wakeup from screen saver time on Mac OS

Tags: macos, logs, screensaver

One can use pmset -g log to get to the info about Wake and Start events of Mac OS. But pmset doesn't seem to make any special assertions to the log when system goes into screen saver mode, and what particularly of interest to me, when the screen saver quits.

What command or log file I can use to find out when the last wake from screen saver event occurred?

Comment: so the "wake reason" does not show it in console log ?

Comment: Yes, I am confident there are no Wake entry for screen saver event, just for real wake. No Sleep entry for going into screen saver either.

Answer (score 1):

Your two filters to type in the Console log would be:

For screen saver activate: `screenshot`

For screen saver end: `DidWake`

Open the Console in the Utility folder and while having selected "all messages" type the above in the filter/search window.

Comment: Which console log? pmset -g log doesn't have those entries for screensaver.

Comment: Macintosh HD/private/var/log/system.log is the file you're looking for.

Comment: I've inspected a system.log. There are entries that include "screenshot" keyword as well as "DidWake", but those defiantly don't get triggered whenever system is showing a screen saver. I have those but they are from different times and some other events.

Comment: Also, I need to know when currently selected screen saver of the system starts and stops, regardless of the nature of what triggered it (timeout or manual moving mouse to hot corner that is setup to start screensaver).

Comment: on my 10.9.5 the Hot corner produces 3/30/15 4:41:34.424 PM WindowServer[84]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04273c00 device: 0x7fde12503ac0  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3

Comment: @Buscar웃, I will check once again and will get back to you. Thank you!